# Jenkins is not getting up, remains in failed state

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I almost done all the available things on the internet even the solution provided at Jenkins community that is yum upgrade as I am using centos 7.6 but nothing worked for me the error is still same. The jenkins version I ma using is 2.346.2.

in Jenkins ,JENKINS_JAVA_CMD="" and the variable is being initialized by the file called
**/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins** which is present under systemd

```
candidates="
/etc/alternatives/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-11.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
/usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.352.b08-2.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java
"
for candidate in $candidates
do
  [ -x "$JENKINS_JAVA_CMD" ] && break
  JENKINS_JAVA_CMD="$candidate"
done
```

The java version is */usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.352.b08-2.el7_9.x86_64*  Which is correct only as I have tried changing it to java 11 then it started popping up new errors. I just used the *jenkins.war.bak* file and revert the state to the previous state. Now, the jenkins service is still in the failed state but I am now able to access the UI of jenkins which was screwed up before.

The error while I tried to restart the service is:

```
[root@localhost log]# systemctl status jenkins
● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Automation Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-07-17 23:34:43 IST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 28719 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 72
   Memory: 1.8G
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           ├─26370 /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3788405557627827271.sh
           ├─26373 python3 main_exec_file.py
           ├─26762 /bin/python /bin/ansible-playbook ./play_books/build_image.yml
           ├─26876 /bin/python /bin/ansible-playbook ./play_books/build_image.yml
           ├─26890 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689616762.75-75003044585972/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0
           ├─26891 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689616762.75-75003044585972/AnsiballZ_command.py
           ├─28722 runuser -s /bin/bash root -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /etc/alternatives/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /u...
           ├─28723 bash -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /etc/alternatives/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkin...
           └─28724 /etc/alternatives/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins....

Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain jenkins[28719]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain jenkins[28719]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain jenkins[28719]: at Main._main(Main.java:342)
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain jenkins[28719]: at Main.main(Main.java:117)
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain runuser[28746]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user root
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain jenkins[28719]: [FAILED]
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Jenkins Automation Server.
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.
Jul 17 23:34:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.
```

I check the space also on my machine it is fine only

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  118G   68G   50G  58% /
devtmpfs                 3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.8G  132K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.8G   98M  3.7G   3% /run
tmpfs                    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               1014M  180M  835M  18% /boot
/dev/loop0               4.8M  4.8M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/yq/1787
/dev/loop1               182M  182M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/postman/179
/dev/loop3                56M   56M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop4               4.8M  4.8M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/yq/1792
/dev/loop2               182M  182M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/postman/178
/dev/loop6                56M   56M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop5                47M   47M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/16010
/dev/loop7                47M   47M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/16292
/dev/mapper/centos-home   19G   18G  809M  96% /home
tmpfs                    766M  4.0K  766M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    766M   52K  766M   1% /run/user/0
overlay                  118G   68G   50G  58% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/07b6cb0d553b90b44b2a2bccb24a20e81637bd76d1cb149acf57eb3671dd6541/merged
```

When I tried accessing the jenkins.log it is provide me the below info

```
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:261)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:538)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:206)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:342)
    at Main.main(Main.java:117)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8089
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:202)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344)
    ... 14 more
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:261)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:538)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:206)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:342)
    at Main.main(Main.java:117)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8089
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:202)
```

I tried to do the **yum upgrade** too but the same issue is persisting for me . I tried restarting my service after changing the java build path too but the error is same.

The pipeline is currently running and failing at few places in the middle.

help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error says that something already use this port

you need to find which program

```
sudo lsof -i:8090
```

or

```
netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':8090'
```